# How to select data of a table from another database in my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have two databases db1 and db2,
how to select data from db1 tb1 while in db2 ?

i try to using the sql as follow ,but it's wrong

```
select db1.* 
from db1.table1 dt1,db1.table2 dt2
where dt1.table1.id = dt2.table2.id
```

please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the error message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are querying directly to the database. Put tables name in select clause `db1.table1.*`.

and also you are using alias of tables in where clause **`where dt1.table1.id = dt2.table2.id`**

try instead of `dt1` = **`db1`** and `dt2` = **`db2`**

```
select db1.table1.* 
from db1.table1 dt1,db1.table2 dt2
where db1.table1.id = db2.table2.id
```

Comment: i try to Put tables name in select clause db1.table1.* , but still get error

Comment: can you put your error here...

Comment: the error msg is  "Table db1.table1 doesn't exist"

Comment: @andrewarnier i have edited the query is it solving the issue or still getting the error

Comment: still getting the error

Comment: @andrewarnier check your table names are correct and you are pointing to correct tables ...

Answer (score 0):

you've aliased the tables in ther from clause, you need to use the same aliases elsewhere in the query too.

```
select dt1.* 
from db1.table1 dt1,db1.table2 dt2
where dt1.id = dt2.id
```